# AsyncTask - Não executa duas vezes

Tags: android, asynctask

estou realizando um processo em meu App, onde na MainActivity, aperto um botão, então ele carrega um JSON em outra Activity que traz todas as informações corretamente..
Porem, quando encerro a tela e tento visualizar novamente a listagem de dados, apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
```

Já pesquisei e analisei em vários lugares que não posso executar duas vezes, tentei instanciar novamente, mas sempre retornar o mesmo erro. Abaixo o código:

Função no MainActivity

```
BackGroundWorkerLO bkwlo = new BackGroundWorkerLO(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    btOve = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btOve);
    btOve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           bkwlo.execute();
        }
    });
```

Classe Assíncrona:

```
public class BackGroundWorkerLO extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context context;

public BackGroundWorkerLO(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String tipo = "lista";
    String url_ovelha = "http://blbiandoge.000webhostapp.com/app/file.json";

    if(tipo.equals("lista")) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_ovelha);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("ErroListaO", "Erro na lista");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Intent intentLO = new Intent(context, ListaOveActivity.class);
    intentLO.putExtra("JSON", s);
    context.startActivity(intentLO);
}
```

Alguem pode ajudar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), há algumas regras que precisam ser seguidas:

1. A classe AsyncTask deve ser carregada na UI.
2. A instância da tarefa deve ser criada na UI.
3. `execute(Params...)` deve ser invocado na UI.
4. Não chamar os métodos `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` e `doInBackground()`
5. A tarefa pode ser executada apenas uma vez

Como você está definindo `BackGroundWorkerLO bkwlo = new BackGroundWorkerLO(this);` fora do segmento UI, quando você chamar o `execute`, o android irá verificar se você já rodou esse código. Caso afirmativo, lançará uma `exception`.

Para evitar isso, você deve criar uma nova instância a cada execução.

```
btOve = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btOve);
btOve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       new BackGroundWorkerLO(view.getContext()).execute();
    }
});
```